# UITableView Random White line in section footer when returning properly sized footer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside of a View created from a NIB.  the table has one section containing 6 rows and 1 footer.  when i use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 80;
}
```

to return the height of the footer, which is being loaded from the same NIB.  the UITableViewCell in the nib has a height of 80. the UITableViewCells are assigned using this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

if (indexPath.section == 0){
  if (indexPath.row == 0){
   return companyCell;
  }

if (indexPath.row == 1){
   return firstNameCell;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 2){
   return lastNameCell;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 3){
   return emailCell;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 4){
   return passwordCell;
  }
  if (indexPath.row == 5){
   return passwordConfirmCell;
  }
 }

```
return passwordConfirmCell;
}
```

i get a white line at the bottom of my table like the image at http://swnsn.com/white.png

if i return a footer height of 79, or 81, the white line goes away and the UITableViewCell scales to the width of the window

any thoughts?

Comment: sorry for the code formatting errors above.  stackoverflow provided a proper preview when i entered it.

Comment: also an image of the 81px footer is at http://swnsn.com/nowhite.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!!  I was passing an instance of UITableViewCell to the footer.  i have update my code to only pass a UIView and the problem has been resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried more row manipulation like this in terms of it's height?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *) theTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
Question *question = [self.questions objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *theText = question.description;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]; // You can choose a different font ofcourse.
int heightExtra = 0;
if (selectedIndexSegment == 0){
    heightExtra = 54;       
}       
if (selectedIndexSegment == 1) {        
    heightExtra = 24;
}   

CGSize withinsize = CGSizeMake(theTableView.frame.size.width -60, 1000); //1000 is  just a large number. could be 500 as well
// You can choose a different Wrap Mode of your choice
CGSize sz = [theText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:withinsize      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return sz.height + heightExtra; // padding space of 20 should be fine!
}
```

And also how about

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];   removes all of the separators from the table too.